# tomcat jdbc SlowQueryReport interceptors - log in a separate file

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, jdbc, intellij-idea

I am trying to log all my slow queries in a separate file. Until now I have to following Tomcat context configuration:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/paymentDB" auth="Container" type="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"
 driverClassName="...oracle..."
...
 jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.QueryTimeoutInterceptor(queryTimeout=2);org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.SlowQueryReport(threshold=1000,maxQueries=200)"
</Context>
```

This works as long as I do not set another kind logger and it prints to the console. One thing that I believe should be added is that I run this test in IntelliJ Idea using default IDE configuration.

The next thing I wanted to do was to log into a separate file. So I opened logging.properties and did the following changes:

```
handlers = ..., 5slowqueries.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, ...
.handlers =..., 5slowqueries.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, ...

5slowqueries.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = ALL
5slowqueries.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
5slowqueries.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = slow-queries.

org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.SlowQueryReport.level = ALL
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.SlowQueryReport.handlers = 5slowqueries.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

The problem is that executing the same slow queries and have been printed earlier in console, this time, using this configuration, no `slow-queries.*` file is created. (I ran this from IntelliJ Idea)

I can't figure out how to make this work. Maybe it has something to do with IDE? I have noticed that IDEA has a Logs category in `Run/Debug Configurations`, I tried to play with these options too but didn't have any luck.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. It was the IDE. When IDEA starts the server it prints something like this in the console:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\..."
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\..."
another few variables
```

The logs are created, by default, if not changed, in CATALINA_BASE/logs.